# Repeated word puzzle – 庭には二羽鶏がいる

Tags: pronunciation

I am thinking of adding more Japanese words or phrases, that have the same pronunciation as には has, to the following sentence.

> 庭{にわ}には二{に}羽{わ}鶏{にわとり}がいる。

Could you help me to find such words (if any)?

Comment: I learned a variant of this which featured a mingling of ニワ with ワニ (as in 鰐 "crocodile"). Something to the effect of 鰐は庭にいる.

Comment: 埴輪 (はにわ), 俄 (にわか), 浪速 (なにわ)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a classic extension of this tongue twister that goes like this:

> 裏庭【うらにわ】には二羽 庭には二羽 ニワトリがいる。
>     (pronounced as うらにわにわにわにわにわにわにわとりがいる)

裏庭 means *backyard*.

Answer (score 5):

Some Japanese tongue twisters.

Level １. Namamugi namagome namatamago( 生麦生米生卵).

Level ２. Tokyotokkyokyokakyoku(東京特許許可局).

Level ３. Kaeru pyokopyoko mipyokopyoko awasete pyokopyoko mupyokopyoko(蛙ぴょこぴょこ三ぴょこぴょこ合わせてぴょこぴょこ六ぴょこぴょこ).

Level ４. Tonarino takegakini taketatekaketanowa taketatekaketakattsutakara taketatekaketa(隣の竹垣に竹立てかけたのは、竹立てかけたかったから、竹立てかけた).

Answer (score 4):

言葉遊び or 早口言葉 would help you.
For example, すももも桃{もも}も桃{もも}のうち