# Any silly Japanese sentences like the "buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo..." one in English?

Tags: words, expressions, word-usage

I made one up, but I was wondering if there were any other good ones.

The one I made up: "王を追う王を追う" (Ou wo ou ou wo ou) ("I chase the king that chases a king").

For those who don't know what I'm referencing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: 「王を覆う王を追う王を覆おう」

Comment: @Angelos, add a "phoenix" on the end there too?  

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/repeated-word-puzzle-%E5%BA%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E4%BA%8C%E7%BE%BD%E9%B6%8F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B

Comment: there's also 「子【ね】子【こ】子【こ】子子子【こねこ】子子【しし】子【こ】子子子【こじし】」 That's the closest to buffalo I know
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90

Comment: @Angelos:  Beat me to it. 

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/repeated-word-puzzle-%E5%BA%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E4%BA%8C%E7%BE%BD%E9%B6%8F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned a long sentence involving kings in the comments myself, and there's 子子子子子子子子子子子子 that shinku mentioned. mbowden linked the classic Niwa's garden tongue twister, which is along similar lines but I don't think it's quite what you're looking for. I'm posting this answer to aggregate these items, and expand on my own sentence slightly, with credit to Eirikr Útendi for the idea.

「鳳凰を覆う王を追う王を覆う王王を覆おう」 'Let's cover King Wang, who covers kings who chase kings that cover fenghuang.'